# Oracle Cloud Instance ARM Ampere Docker NGINX error

Tags: docker, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am facing an error when I try to run a docker container on an instance with ARM Ampere. When I run it on AMD, it works properly.

It seems to be related to the sort of processor, I am not sure about, but that was the only change I've made.

Can someone help?

Error:

```
ERROR [shopexample_nginx 2/5] RUN wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/v0.6.1/dockerize-alpi  1.4s
 => CACHED [shopexample_app  1/10] FROM docker.io/library/php:8.0.2-fpm-buster@sha256:b9adc59273171d12e243e4185d83cbdb7  0.0s
 => CANCELED [shopexample_app  2/10] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y     openssl     wget     zlib1g-dev    2.8s
------
 > [shopexample_nginx 2/5] RUN wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/v0.6.1/dockerize-alpine-linux-amd64-v0.6.1.tar.gz     && tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-alpine-linux-amd64-v0.6.1.tar.gz     && rm dockerize-alpine-linux-amd64-v0.6.1.tar.gz:
#0 0.329 Connecting to github.com (140.82.112.3:443)
#0 0.334 wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-alpine-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz     && tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-alpine-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz     && rm dockerize-alpine-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz]: exit code: 1
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build: docker/app
    container_name: app
    entrypoint: ./docker/app/entrypoint.sh
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./docker/app/prod.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx:
    build: docker/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    entrypoint: ./docker/nginx/entrypoint.sh
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      WAIT: -wait tcp://app:9000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - app


networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a `php:8.0.2-fpm-buster` image that is x86_64 and you need to use an image appropriate to the architecture you're using in your VM.

If you are using Ampere processor they are arm64 architecture. Then look for a php image for arm64.

https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/php/

Use `arm64v8/` in your `FROM` statement in your `Dockerfile`. Like this:

```
FROM arm64v8/php:8.0.2-fpm-buster
```